# Seekbar: менять данные на лету

Tags: android, java

Я использую данный Seekbar:  https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/

Можно изменять конечные и начальные данные. Он работает, но данные меняются, только когда убираешь палец от экрана, а надо, чтобы данные менялись на лету. Я не смог это реализовать. 
Может, есть какая-нибудь другая подобная библиотека, где можно менять данные с обоих концов и на лету?

**Обновление**

Я применяю MotionEvent:

```
    seekBar.setOnGenericMotionListener(new View.OnGenericMotionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGenericMotion(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.e("ScreenTwoSeekBar", event.getY() + " " + event.getX() + " " + " " + event.getActionIndex() + " " + event.getAction());
            return false;
        }
    });
```

В итоге выходят только три события, но движения нету, только начальные и конечные данные, в логах выходит

```
01-09 05:44:21.318    1541-1541/com.example.eldos.callreport E/ScreenTwoSeekBar﹕ 50.785522 865.1545  0 10
01-09 05:44:23.518    1541-1541/com.example.eldos.callreport E/ScreenTwoSeekBar﹕ 22.80011 775.23773  0 9
01-09 05:44:23.518    1541-1541/com.example.eldos.callreport E/ScreenTwoSeekBar﹕ 22.80011 775.23773  0 7
```

При касании выходит событие 10, при отпускании выходит 9 и 7, как можно отлавливать движения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
seekBar.setNotifyWhileDragging(true);
```

Comment: Спасибо, как раз только хотел алгоритм продумать 

        seekBar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public double left = 0;
            public double right = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                Log.e("ScreenTwoSeekBar", event.getX() + " " + " " + event.getAction());

                return false;
            }
        });

Comment: Можно спросить, как вы узнали об этой функции, я как бы искал эту информацию, но не смог найти.

Comment: И еще вопрос: а можно как-то отделить эти детали, чтобы, к примеру, когда палец движется, был один обработчик, а когда он отпустит, другой обработчик?
Или придется все-таки придется работать с

    setOnTouchListener

Comment: Беглый просмотр исходников на обращение к OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener.

Comment: Ok, понял, наверное, я в исходниках что-то исправлю, дабы реализовать еще один обработчик, спасибо.  
Достаточно было только добавить еще один интерфейс. )